# What is the difference between Nasion and Root of Nose?

Tags: terminology, anatomy, face

I am now studying the area of the nose and getting acquainted with the anatomy of this place - I came across these two terms.

I originally thought that Nazion is where Frontal bone and Nasal bones meats. And then in one of the sources on the Internet I find out that this place is called the Root of Nose, and Nazion is a little higher.

I thought that above the root of the nose is Glabella and not some kind of Nazion. What role does this Nazion have? Just to mark the place between Glabella and the root of the nose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Radiopeadia](https://doi.org/10.53347/rID-22725) helps with locating the nasion.

> The nasion (also known as bridge of the nose) is the midline bony depression between the eyes where the frontal and two nasal bones meet, just below the glabella.

They cite Moore & Dalley (1999) for reference.

[The NIH website provides a way](https://elementsofmorphology.nih.gov/anatomy-nose.shtml) to locate the root of the nose and where it is in relation to the nasion. It is the

> most depressed, superior part of the nose along the nasal ridge.

[image: The anatomy of the nose]
<sup>Image source: https://elementsofmorphology.nih.gov/anatomy-nose.shtml</sup>

### References

Moore, K. L., & Dalley, A. F. (1999). Clinically oriented anatomy. Lippincott Williams & Wilkins, Philadelphia. *PJ Kelly, Editor*, 550-575. ISBN: 1451119453